# Showing $\frac n {log_2 n} = \Omega (n^{\frac 1 {100}})$ and another

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Prove:
>
> 1. $\frac n {log_2 n} = \Omega (n^{\frac 1 {100}})$
> 2. $3^{log_a {n}} = O(3^{log_b {n}})$ where $a>b>0$

For 1 we need to show that: $\frac n {log_2 n} \ge c (n^{\frac 1 {100}})$ I don't see an easy way to do it, also taking a limit of their quotient isn't simple either, the result after just one LHR is even more complicated, so I don't know how to continue.

For 2, I'm not sure how to solve their quotient limit, so I tried:

$3^{log_a {n}} \le c (3^{log_b {n}}) \Rightarrow 3^{log_a {n}-log_b {n}}  \le c \Rightarrow 3^{log_a {n}-log_a {n}/log_a {b}}  \le c $ and I'm stuck again.

Comment: For the second: $3^{\log_a n} = 2^{\log n \frac{\log 3}{\log a}}$, and $3^{\log_b n} = 2^{\log n \frac{\log 3}{\log b}}$. Now, $\log b < \log a$, so... (by the way, are you sure it's $>0$, not $>1$?)

Comment: Yeah it's $0$ but it could be an error. How did you change the base from $3$ to $2$? @ClementC.

Comment: 3=2^(log 3) (binary logarithm)